# Corner detection not accurate

Tags: java, opencv, corner-detection

I'm trying to detect corners, but the coordinates I get are always off-center and saddle-points are detected Multiple times.

I tried `cornerHarris`, `cornerMinEigenVal`, `preCornerDetect`, `goodFeaturesToTrack`, and `cornerEigenValsAndVecs`, but they all seem to lead to the same result. I haven't tried `findChessboardCorners` because my corners are not laid out in a nice grid of n×m, are not all saddle-type, and many more reasons.

What I have now:

Given the (pre-processed) camera image below with some positive, negative, and saddle corners:

[image: demo]

After `cornerHarris(img, energy, 20, 9, 0.1)` (I increased `blockSize` to 20 for illustrative purposes but small values don't work either) I get this image:

[image: demo]

It seems to detect 10 corners but the way they are positioned is odd. I superimposed this image on the original to show my problem:

[image: demo]

The point of highest matching energy is offset towards the inside of the corner and there is a plume pointing away from the corner. The saddle corners seem to generate four separate plumes all superimposed.

Indeed, when I perform a corner-search using this energy image, I get something like:

[image: demo] / [image: demo]

What am I doing wrong and how can I detect corners accurately like in this mock image?

[image: demo]

[[edit]] MCVE:

```
public class CornerTest {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }

    private static Mat energy = new Mat();
    private static Mat idx    = new Mat();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Mat byteImage = Highgui.imread("KXw7O.png");
        if (byteImage.channels() > 1)
            Imgproc.cvtColor(byteImage, byteImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        // Preprocess
        Mat floatImage = new Mat();
        byteImage.convertTo(floatImage, CvType.CV_32F);

        // Corner detect
        Mat imageToShow = findCorners(floatImage);

        // Show in GUI
        imageToShow.convertTo(byteImage, CvType.CV_8U);
        BufferedImage bufImage = new BufferedImage(byteImage.width(), byteImage.height(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        byte[] imgArray = ((DataBufferByte)bufImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        byteImage.get(0, 0, imgArray);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bufImage)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static Mat findCorners(Mat image) {
        Imgproc.cornerHarris(image, energy, 20, 9, 0.1);

        // Corner-search:

        int minDistance = 16;
        Core.MinMaxLocResult minMaxLoc = Core.minMaxLoc(
                energy.submat(20, energy.rows() - 20, 20, energy.rows() - 20));
        float thr = (float)minMaxLoc.maxVal / 4;

        Mat tmp = energy.reshape(1, 1);
        Core.sortIdx(tmp, idx, 16); // 16 = CV_SORT_EVERY_ROW | CV_SORT_DESCENDING

        int[] idxArray = new int[idx.cols()];
        idx.get(0, 0, idxArray);
        float[] energyArray = new float[idx.cols()];
        energy.get(0, 0, energyArray);

        int n = 0;
        for (int p : idxArray) {
            if (energyArray[p] == -1) continue;
            if (energyArray[p] < thr) break;
            n++;

            int x = p % image.cols();
            int y = p / image.cols();

            // Exclude a disk around this corner from potential future candidates
            int u0 = Math.max(x - minDistance, 0) - x;
            int u1 = Math.min(x + minDistance, image.cols() - 1) - x;
            int v0 = Math.max(y - minDistance, 0) - y;
            int v1 = Math.min(y + minDistance, image.rows() - 1) - y;
            for (int v = v0; v <= v1; v++)
                for (int u = u0; u <= u1; u++)
                    if (u * u + v * v <= minDistance * minDistance)
                        energyArray[p + u + v * image.cols()] = -1;

            // A corner is found!
            Core.circle(image, new Point(x, y), minDistance / 2, new Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1);
            Core.circle(energy, new Point(x, y), minDistance / 2, new Scalar(minMaxLoc.maxVal, minMaxLoc.maxVal, minMaxLoc.maxVal), 1);
        }
        System.out.println("nCorners: " + n);

        // Rescale energy image for display purpose only

        Core.multiply(energy, new Scalar(255.0 / minMaxLoc.maxVal), energy);

//      return image;
        return energy;
    }
}
```